# How to use third party plugin inside Cypress version 11 latest version?

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, cypress, end-to-end

We are trying to migrate from cypress v8 to cypress v11.

We were using [cypress-wait-until](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-wait-until) and [cypress-plugin-tab](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-plugin-tab)

As the support file configuration is now deprecated, tried to import these support inside `cypress.config.ts`

But after importing getting error as `ReferenceError: Cypress is not defined`

What is the correct way of configuration, any example will be helpful and appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These libraries use neither config nor nodejs, so `cypress.config.js` is not the place you should be using them.

The place to import them is `/cypress/support/e2e.js`

Please read about the support file in the Cypress docs here: [Support file](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests#Support-file)